# Remove odd int node from linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am calling this method on a Linked List that contains 5 nodes with int data <4, 3 ,2 ,1 ,5>  
I want to remove odd ints and return <4, 2>

I ran in main method   mylist.removeOdds
It seems to be working properly but never deletes (assigns the previous node to the current next) 

***output*** 
This output keeps going until i terminate

while condition loop entered

current element 3 previous element4

if condition met 

current element 3 previous element4

if condition met 

current element 3 previous element4

if condition met

```
Public void removeOdds() {
    Node current = head;
    Node previous=null;
    while ((current.getNext()) != null) {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
        } else {
            while (current != null && (current.getElement()) % 2 != 1) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
                System.out.println("while condition loop entered");
                System.out.println("current element " + current.getElement()+" previous element "+ previous.getElement());
            }
            if ((current.getElement()) % 2 == 1) {
                 System.out.println("if condition met ");
                previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                System.out.println("current element " + current.getElement()+" previous element "+ previous.getElement());

            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After the below statement -

```
previous.setNext(current.getNext());
```

You need to add this statement

```
current.setNext(current.getNext());
```

Comment: #codeMan is Correct. you are not advancing the linst after the if condition is met. Hence it keeps Looping until you terminate.

Answer (score -1):

You had better provide the structure of Node Class.

```
Public void removeOdds() {
Node current = head;
Node previous=null;
while ((current.getNext()) != null) {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("The list is empty");
    } else {
        while (current != null && (current.getElement()) % 2 != 1) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
            System.out.println("while condition loop entered");
            System.out.println("current element " + current.getElement()+" previous element "+ previous.getElement());
        }
        if ((current.getElement()) % 2 == 1) {
             System.out.println("if condition met ");
            previous.setNext(current.getNext());
            current=current.getNext();
            System.out.println("current element " + current.getElement()+" previous element "+ previous.getElement());

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't follow? There is a Node class not pictured here, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: The code I provided you just now is modified, you can copy it to your IDE to try.

Comment: your code worked, but it didnt delete 5, the last odd number in the list. Im thinking it has something to do with setting the tail.